# Highcharts: xAxis label above bar in horizontal bar charts

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set bar labels 'above bar' and I'm using `xAxis.label.x` property to accomplish it. However, I'm noticing that distances between bar and label slightly different. If you look at the fiddle,(I tried to position labels as close as possible) some of them have less distance than others. Is this rounding issue? Is there a way to avoid it? Please advise.

https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/fmnysehq/32/

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
            pointPadding: 0,
  }
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014'],
    labels: {
                    x: 0,
        align: 'left',
        reserveSpace: false,
        y: -20,
    },
        min: -0.2,
      max: 4.2,
    tickWidth: 0
},
yAxis: {
visible: false
},

series: [{
    data: [39.9, 71.5, 106.4, 23, 67],
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
}]
```

});

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `pointPlacement` option from the series it will work fine.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014'],
    labels: {
      x: 0,
      align: 'left',
      reserveSpace: false,
      y: -12,
    }
  },


  series: [{
    data: [39.9, 71.5, 106.4, 23, 67],
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: If you take closer look on bottom of each label, you'll see 1px difference, some of the labels cover bars a little. it's hardly noticeable but it's there

Comment: I can't see it, check here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4dfcgk0z/

Answer (score 0):

that seems to be a rendering issue in Highcharts (as many others), however you can get a way better result using this settings:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Default title',
        margin: 50
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
                pointPadding: 0,
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014'],
        labels: {
            x: 5,
            align: 'left',
            reserveSpace: false,
            y: 33,
        },
            min: -0.2,
          max: 4.2,
        tickWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
    visible: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [39.9, 71.5, 106.4, 23, 67],
        pointPlacement: 'between',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }]
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Davo, I don't think that solution you proposed would work in my case. Labels should be above chart. Thanks for try!